# C Pthread: Possible Deadlock, Thread 1 hangs while Thread 2 Exits

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am very new to system programming in C, I am using pthreads to create two threads that increments a counter and display the value. Thread 1 increments if the counter value is even and Thread 2 increments if counter value is odd.

```
pthread_mutex_t count_mutex     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  condition_var   = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *functionCount1();
void *functionCount2();
int  count = 0;
#define COUNT_DONE  2

int main()
{
   pthread_t thread1, thread2;

   pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &functionCount1, NULL);
   pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &functionCount2, NULL);

   pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

   printf("Final count: %d\n",count);

   exit(0);
}


void *functionCount1()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );

        pthread_cond_wait( &condition_var, &count_mutex );
        count++;
        printf("Counter value functionEven: %d\n",count);

        pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

        if(count >= COUNT_DONE) {
            printf("Thread 1: Exit condition reached.\n");
            return(NULL); 

        }
    }
}

void *functionCount2()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );

        if( count % 2 == 0)
        {
            pthread_cond_signal( &condition_var );
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
            printf("Counter value functionOdd: %d.\n",count); 
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

        if(count >= COUNT_DONE) {
            printf("Thread 2: Exit condition reached.\n");
            return(NULL); 
        }
    }

}
```

From what I can observe, the problem is that Thread 2 reaches it exist condition first and it leave Thread 1 hanging.

```
Counter value functionEven: 1
Counter value functionOdd: 2.
Thread 2: Exit condition reached.
(This is where it hangs, I have to press Ctrl-C to end)^C
```

I have tried to a another lock when thread 2 reaches its exit condition and unlock it only when thread 1 exist condition is invoked. But this doesn't seem to do anything.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

if(count >= COUNT_DONE) {
    printf("Thread 1: Exit condition reached.\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex2 );
    return(NULL); 
}

if(count >= COUNT_DONE) {
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex2 );
    printf("Thread 2: Exit condition reached.\n");
    return(NULL); 
}
```

**Final solution with proper count.**

Answer below helped a lot and it solved main problem.

```
pthread_cond_wait( &condition_var, &count_mutex );
if(count >= COUNT_DONE) {
    return(NULL); 
}
count++;
printf("Counter value functionEven: %d\n",count);
```

Comment: You have a data race because variable count is not protected in the two if statements. Thus the behavior is undefined. I was meaning to post a full answer, but I wasn't sure what the intention of the code is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before exiting functionCount2, you must signal your conditional variable as follows;

```
    if(count >= COUNT_DONE) {
        printf("Thread 2: Exit condition reached.\n");
        pthread_cond_signal( &condition_var );
        return(NULL);
    }
```